# Consulta: guardar datos de un datagridview (C#) en base de datos sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, datagridview

Estimados buenas noches

Les realizo la siguiente consulta, tengo el siguiente DataGridView:

[image: Datagridview]

Codigo C#:

```
 public String RegistrarDetalleVenta()
        {
            bool rta = false;
            String sql = "INSERT INTO DetalleVenta (id_comida, id_venta, cantidad, precio,total) VALUES (@id_comida, @id_venta, @cantidad, @precio, @total)";
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = PracticaSupervisada; Integrated Security = True"))
               foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)

                {
                    cn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_comida", id_comida);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_venta", id_venta);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", cantidad);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precio", precio);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", total);

                    rta = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
                    cn.Close();
                }
         
            return "";
        }
```

Osea quiero que me guarde todas las comidas que voy cargando en el datagridview, pero como estoy poniendo que me guarde todas las filas, me las esta guardando asi:

[image: Base de datos sql server]

Osea me guarda tambien la fila vacia y la fila que dice total y el total del importe( osea las ultimas 2 filas). Como tengo que poner para que no me guarde las ultimas dos filas del datagridview?? se me quemaron los libros mal

Answer (score 0):

Te esta guardando así porque no estas actualizando los datos que pasas en el `foreach`.
Como respondí en otra pregunta, te recomiendo separar la lógica de negocio y comunicación de la BD, del formulario en si.

Esta recomendación te sirve para poder controlar y mantener la integridad de los datos. Por ejemplo, se puede observa que no estas commiteando los insert que estas haciendo.

En SQL SERVER no Tenes drama, pero en otros motores de BD si no commiteas no te guarda nada, en otros casos te guarda datos pero al cerrar la conexión esos datos los perdes, siempre es importante commitear. Otra cosa que no estas controlando, es un posible error de conexión con la BD, si en el medio del foreach ,la conexión tiene un problema o se cierra, y vos hiciste varios inserts vas a perder la integridad de los datos. Tenes que aplicar el concepto de transacciones, super importante hacer esto. Viendo el nombre del metodo, veo que queres guardar una venta con su detalle, esto lo deberías hacer todo junto.

Si solo queres arreglar tu código para que funcione tendrías que probar con esto:

```
 public bool RegistrarDetalleVenta()
{

    String sql = "INSERT INTO DetalleVenta (id_comida, id_venta, cantidad, precio,total) VALUES (@id_comida, @id_venta, @cantidad, @precio, @total)";

    string_conexion = "Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = PracticaSupervisada; Integrated Security = True";

    int contadorFilasNoVacias;
    int afectadas;//filas que se insertaron en la BD

    contadorFilasNoVacias = 0;
    afectadas = 0;

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlTransaction t = null;// esto se usa para sentencias del tipo INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.   

    try
    {
        cnn.ConnectionString = string_conexion;
        cnn.Open();

        t = cnn.BeginTransaction();//inicia la transaccion

        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
        {
            if ( !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()))//valido que la primera celda tenga algun valor, en tu ejemplo la primera celda tiene la cantidad, asi que si no hay cantidad asumo que no deberia agregarla.
            {
                contadorFilasNoVacias++;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_comida", row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_venta", row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precio", row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                //ACA EN LOS PARAMETROS TENES QUE PONER EL NUMERO DE COLUMNA CORRESPONDIENTE
                // Y EL TIPO DE VALOR CORRESPONDIENTE, YO PUSE TODO STRING ASUMIENDO QUE BD RECIBE VARCHAR
                cmd.Transaction = t;
                afectadas += cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }       
        }

        //dada la logica de como inserto, esta validacion esta demas, asi como el contador de filas vacias, pero si por las dudas queres agregar un control mas, deberias hacer esto.
        if (afectadas == contadorFilasNoVacias)//valido que haya insertado las filas correctas si es true commiteo los cambios y si no hago un rollback y la BD queda como antes.
        {
            t.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            t.Rollback();
            afectadas = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (t != null)
        {
            t.Rollback();
            afectadas = 0;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("EXPLOTO ALGO", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.CloseConnection(cnn);
    }

    return afectadas == contadorFilasNoVacias;
    //si se insertaron las filas correctadas estos 2 contadores van a tener el mismo valor. 
    //Dada la logica, si no salta la excepcion, estos valores siempre van a ser iguales 
    //porque estoy haciendo que inserte fila con valores. Se puede retornar esta igualdad o sea puede retornar como la linea de abajo
    //return afectadas > 0;
}

private void CloseConnection(SqlConnection cnn)
{
    if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        cnn.Close();
        cnn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Avísame si te tira algún error de compilación o alguna excepción, ya que, pude haber olvidado algo.

Comment: Antes que nada gracias por tu explicacion Franco. Consulta, el id_comida es int asi que calculo que en vez de poner cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_comida", row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());  deberia poner cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_comida", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString())); verdad ? tambien te queria consultar por el string_conexion, me dice que no existe en el contexto actual, genero una variable o campo de lectura para esto?

Comment: Claro, yo lo puse así nomas a la variable, pero la tenes que declarar, yo la declararía en la clase o como te decía en otra clase aparte. Porque si no la vas a tener que declarar en cada método que llame a la BD. Con respecto al parametro, estas en lo correcto tenes que indicarle el mismo tipo o similar al de la BD. Por ejemplo, si la BD acepta double y vos lo queres pasar como float, no hay problema. Por el contrario, si la BD es float y vos le pasas double, en algunos casos podes llegar a tener error según el valor que pases.